# Visual Studio Code ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_overlapped'

Tags: python

I have developed the following message when running flask. I attempted to add overlapped, via pip install overlap. I can't find answers to this. This is my terminal output. Can someone please help?

```
dvdjms@DESKTOP-OPG4GRH:/mnt/c/Users/dvdjm/Documents/CS50/project$ flask run
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dvdjms/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 218, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/dvdjm/Documents/CS50/project/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/windows_events.py", line 3, in <module>
    import _overlapped
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_overlapped'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to import `NULL` from `asyncio.windows_event`? I'm guessing it was automatically imported by your IDE, `None` is likely what you're looking for instead of `NULL`, which isn't a keyword in Python.

Comment: To be honest I don't actually understand asyncio.windows_event nor remember trying to import it. However, I attempted what you said and got this repsonse;
from: can't read /var/mail/asyncio.windows_events

Comment: Leave it with me. I'm unsure I need help at the moment.

Comment: That usually happens whenever the shell is trying to execute a python script instead of Python. Try running the script with `python script.py` or put `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the first line of your script.

Comment: I hadn't realised I added 'from asyncio.windows_event import NULL'. It must have been there for days so don't know why it suddenly caused trouble. Thank you, though. You sent me in the right direction. I just deleted the line - I don't think I need it.